# JavaScript focus: How to focus on and stay there?

Tags: javascript

I need the following:

1. User clicks on the checkbox.
2. Focus moves to the textbox.
3. And stay there. In the textbox.

I try to use Javascript:

```
 if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id){
     var comment = mtv.getCellByColumnUniqueName(rows[i], "Comment01").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].id;
     document.getElementById(comment).focus();
     break;
 }
```

And it works. The Focus is going to textbox but **immediately** go out of textbox.
But I need the focus to stay in textbox until the user types anything.

Is it real?

UPD: All my js code for 3 checkboxes and one textbox:

```
function gridValuesEdits(sender, args) {
      clearCheckboxes(sender, args);
      comments(sender, args);
}

function clearCheckboxes(sender, args)
{
  switch (args.get_columnUniqueName())
  {
    case "chbx00":
      if (args.get_editorValue())
      {
        var grid = $findByControlId("Grid4"); 
        var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = mtv.get_dataItems();
        var batchEditingManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
          if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id)
          {
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[8], false);
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[9], false);
            batchEditingManager.endUpdate();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    case "chbx01":
      if (args.get_editorValue())
      {
        var grid = $findByControlId("Grid4"); 
        var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = mtv.get_dataItems();
        var batchEditingManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
          if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id)
          {
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[7], false);
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[9], false);
            batchEditingManager.endUpdate();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    case "chbx02":
      if (args.get_editorValue())
      {
        var grid = $findByControlId("Grid4"); 
        var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = mtv.get_dataItems();
        var batchEditingManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
          if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id)
          {
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[7], false);
            batchEditingManager.changeCellValue(rows[i]._element.cells[8], false);
            batchEditingManager.endUpdate();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function comments(sender, args)
{
  switch (args.get_columnUniqueName())
  {
    case "chbx01":
      if (args.get_editorValue())
      {
        var grid = $findByControlId("Grid4"); 
        var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = mtv.get_dataItems();
        var batchEditingManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
          if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id)
          {
            vvar comment = mtv.getCellByColumnUniqueName(rows[i], "Comment01").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].id;
     document.getElementById(comment).focus();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    case "chbx02":
      if (args.get_editorValue())
      {
        var grid = $findByControlId("Grid4"); 
        var mtv = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = mtv.get_dataItems();
        var batchEditingManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
        {
          if (rows[i].get_element().id==args.get_row().id)
          {
            var comment = mtv.getCellByColumnUniqueName(rows[i], "Comment01").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].id;
     document.getElementById(comment).focus();
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not good User Experience. 
Read about Aria, tabindex, accessibility. You should not move the focus in any unexpected way.

Comment: Does you interface re-render somehow? It can cause your textarea loses the focus.

Comment: I use PNM Sequence. And I need to use javascript in order to move the focus because the sequence has not any suitable function

Comment: @Daut With this little information, we can't say whether moving the focus is good or bad. There are perfectly fine reasons to use it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I said unexpected way. 

Moving the focus from a checkbox is not good, as a screenreader will say "checked" and then will start saying all kinds of other information e.g. the lable of the textbox, without the user wanting to move to the input.

It will be like moving the cursor of a user over an input field after they click somewhere. It is not a good way of doing it from accessibility point of view

Answer (score 0):

Something else must be "stealing" the focus after you've set it. As you can see below, setting the focus to the textbox works just fine.

```js
// When the checkbox is clicked....
document.querySelector("[type='checkbox']").addEventListener("click", function(){
  let tb = document.querySelector("[type='text']");
  
  if(this.checked){ 
    tb.classList.remove("hidden");  // Unhide the textbox
    tb.focus();                     // Set the focus on the text box
  } else {
    tb.classList.add("hidden");     // Hide the textbox
    this.focus();                   // Put the focus on the checkbox  
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox">Click to add details</label>
<input type="text" class="hidden">
```

Comment: Well, I think I know what function can "steal" the focus (another checkbox). How can I except it?

Comment: @NaSt Another checkbox can't steal the focus. Only some code can steal the focus.

Comment: I have js code for three checkboxes. And at the same time only two can be switched on. Maybe the focus goes to textbox first and after that immediately goes to switch off the checkbox. But how to set the priority?

Comment: @NaSt You'll need to edit your question to include more of what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, I added all js for all three checkboxes and one textbox